# Pentaho spoon transformation from excel file

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, etl, kettle

I have yearly data in my excel file in such format:

```
Country \ Years   1980   1981   ...   2010
Abkhazia           234    334   ...    456
Afghanistan        466    789   ...    732
...
```

Here is picture[image: hydro production data]

And I want my data transform to 3 different tables and load it to postgres database.

Tables should look something like that

First table - country:

```
id | name
1  | Abkhazia
2  | Afghanistan
```

Second table dates:

```
id | date
1  | 1980
2  | 1981
```

And third is a table where all data is stored depending on country and date:

```
country_id    date_id   data
         1          1    234
         1          2    334
         2          1    466
         2          2    789
       ...        ...    ...
```

Any ideas how I could achieve my goal?

Comment: your input seems not clear.. 
Can you please tell me the actual source file structure.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. Hi, I added a screenshot, hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the source excel structure is as below *(i have custom built this)*:

[image: Source]

There are basically 3 parts to your question. I break down the transformation into part for better understanding:

**1. Loading Table - Country**

This is pretty straight forward based on the data given in the excel. Simply take an

`Excel Input >> Add a sequence step. Give the Sequence name as Country ID >> Select only the Country Name and Country ID >> Load into the Country Table using Table Output`.

[image]

[image: Loading Country Table]

**2. Loading Table - Year:**

The idea here is to display the Year ID in Row wise format instead of the columns given the excel source data. PDI version 5 and above provides you with a very useful step called [Metadata Structure](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Metadata+Structure). This step allows you to get the structure of your table. In this case, we need to have the year columns pulled, ignoring the country column.

[image]

Follow the steps as below:

`Read the Excel Data >> Get the Metadata structure of your source >> Filter Out the Country Column (which is available in row at position=1) >> Add a Sequence Number. Name it YearID >> Finally Load the Year Table.`

[image]

**3. Loading the Final Table - Country and Year along with Data:**

[image]

The way to display all the column data values to a row level in PDI is using [Row Normalizer](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Row+Normaliser) step. Use this step to display a normalized output. Now follow the below steps:

`Read the Excel source data >> use Row Normalizer Step to normalize the rows based on the Years >> Do a Stream Lookup with the Above Country and Year tables to fetch the CountryID and YearID respectively >> Finally Load the necessary column data into Table Output`

[image]

Hope it helps :)

---

I have placed the codes in github repo along with the data file which i have used. Its [here](https://github.com/rishuatgithub/Pentaho/tree/master/ModifyingExcel).

Also, just realized that i have given the wrong naming conventions as per your question. Consider date_id as YearID and instead of id's i have given countryid and yearid.